# Add TextView dinnamically when clicks another button

Tags: android

I'm trying add only one more `TextView` on my Layout. Since start I've got only one `TextView` but I would like to get a button which when I click on it adds another `TextView`dinnamically.
I thought adding this [library](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout) because since it's only one `TextView` it would work...

Well with an example it's easier to understand it's something like an alarm dat you have got a  `TextView` with `HH:MM` and if you want you can add another `TextView` with `HH:MM`. It's better using a `Library` or just do it programmatically since start?

### Edit

XML CODE :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rt1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:id="@+id/pew1">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btNerd"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btNerd"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btNerd">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:text="First"/>
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

But it saying

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

On my Java I've got this

```
btNerd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btNerd);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btNerd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView text2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            text2.setText("Text2");
            lv1.addView(text2);
        }
});
```

But the problem is on the xml I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a library just to add a TextView to your Layout.

Example:

layout.xml

```
<Linearlayout android:id="@+id/list" android:orientation="vertical"> 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" android:text="some text here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java (in Activity):

```
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);  
TextView text2 = new TextView(this);  
text2.setText("some more text");  
list.addView(text2);
```

Comment: better use a Linearlayout, I forgot how ListViews behave in xml - see edit

Comment: It doesn't put below the other TextView you know why?

Comment: you can use addView(view, index) to add a view at a specific index.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how ListView works.

ListView needs an adapter to bind the data and views. You can look for some tutorials about `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter`.

If you just want to add a TextView into a ViewGroup. Just replace your ListView with `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.